# Multiple-set membership testing using a Bloom Tree in Java

Tags: java, tree, set, membership, bloom-filter

I need to solve a multiple-set membership testing problem. There can be a large number of keys for every value, and it needs to be fast. The problem has been theoretically (and practically) solved, as e.g. hardware routers have similar problems.

There is a description of an optimized solution in this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6848077

There is however no implementation in any language other than math. The closest match I could find is this: https://github.com/lemire/bloofi

Is there anything else? Any JVM language is fine, or failing that, any other programming language so I could translate it myself.

Comment: I wonder, can an entry be in multiple sets at the same time? If not, then you could use one of the data structures described in the paper "Succinct Data Structures for Retrieval and Approximate Membership". There are some practical implementations for this, at https://github.com/FastFilter/fastfilter_java (cuckoo and xor filter) - even thought, some work is needed to make the API useful. I could help with this, but would need to know more info.

Comment: Yes, and entry can be in multiple sets. In that case the entry is invalid, but we need to detect this situation. I didn't see multi-set membership mentioned in the FastFilter repo specifically, which is as far as I understand the only way to not only check for membership, but map keys to values. Did I miss anything? (huge fan of H2 btw.!)

Comment: What you can do with a cuckoo filter is, when adding an entry, don't just add a fingerprint like you normally would (cuckoo filters use fingerprints, unlike Bloom filters). Instead, add a fingerprint _plus_ a payload (say, 8 bits fingerprint, 8 bits payload). The payload then tells you in which set (or sets) the entry belongs to. When doing a lookup, you don't just get "true" or "false", but a list of payloads (empty list means not in the set). With the xor filter, you are guaranteed to get either one or zero entries. But xor filters are immutable. So not sure if that might work for your case.

Comment: Ah that is interesting, thanks for the explanation. I'll have a look at the cuckoo filters, they might fit the bill.